# answers Quarkus unit-testing and properties

Tags: quarkus

In Qaurkus Project while I am running with an in-memory Profile so runs OK . so I want to run my Junit5 with an in-memory profile, how so i can do this , if anyone has suggestion about this.

Comment: Hi, can you try to clarify the question? I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: i want to run Quarkus Unit test with in-memory profile .

Comment: because in my quarkus project run in with in-memory profile .

Comment: when I am trying to run quarkus unit test default then it give a 500 error.

Comment: What do you mean by `in-memory` profile?

Comment: it is a one  profile kind of thing. for running quarkus microservice.